# Как узнать есть ли петля в графе?

Tags: c++, графы, олимпиада

Не знаю как решить ? Можете сказать как можно решить эту задачу ?

По заданной матрице смежности неориентированного графа определите, содержит ли он петли.

Входные данные

В первой строке задано количество вершин n (1 ≤ n ≤ 100). Затем идут n строк по n элементов в каждой - описание матрицы смежности.
Выходные данные

Вывести "YES", если граф содержит петли, и "NO" в противном случае.

```
Входные данные #1

3
0 1 1
1 0 1
1 1 0

Выходные данные #1

NO

Входные данные #2

3
0 1 0
1 1 1
0 1 0

Выходные данные #2

YES
```

Comment: Всё-таки петля или цикл?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Петля - это ребро из вершины в нее же.
Из `i` в `i`.
Т.е. ненулевой диагональный элемент :)
Сами запрограммируете или помогать надо? :-)

Comment: если не смогу ,вам напишу .

Answer (score 0):

```
if(a[i][i] == 1)
cout << "YES";
return;
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]